# Python openCV - very long time of processing video

Tags: python, opencv

I have to process video to grayscale and then perform dithering on it. Everything works fine, however processing 16 sec video last 1,5h. Basically it take more or less 10-20sec for each frame. I have never processed any video but heard it is very heavy process so just wanted to make sure if it is normal or if my algorithm is wrong?

that's how dithering algorithm looks like:

```
def minmax(v):
    if v > 255:
        v = 255
    if v < 0:
        v = 0
    return v


def dithering_gray(inMat, samplingF):
    # grab the image dimensions
    h = inMat.shape[0]
    w = inMat.shape[1]

    for y in range(0, h - 1):
        for x in range(1, w - 1):
            old_p = inMat[y, x]
            new_p = np.round(samplingF * old_p / 255.0) * (255 / samplingF)
            inMat[y, x] = new_p

            quant_error_p = old_p - new_p

            inMat[y, x + 1] = minmax(inMat[y, x + 1] + quant_error_p * 7 / 16.0)
            inMat[y + 1, x - 1] = minmax(inMat[y + 1, x - 1] + quant_error_p * 3 / 16.0)
            inMat[y + 1, x] = minmax(inMat[y + 1, x] + quant_error_p * 5 / 16.0)
            inMat[y + 1, x + 1] = minmax(inMat[y + 1, x + 1] + quant_error_p * 1 / 16.0)

    return inMat
```

Comment: What slowing you down so much is running through everything in for loops. Instead try to vectorize your operations with numpy.

Comment: I think the fact you have an accumulating error will make it difficult to vectorise your code and I think your code could be converted to run under `numba` quite easily and very effectively. Try putting `[numba]` in the search box to see examples. Consider adding the `numba` tag.

Comment: @MarkSetchell omg awesome! Now whole video process for 30 sec instead of one and half hour! Thank you so much man

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project. If you feel like contributing to the SO community and sharing your code as the answer that might help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to answer in comments I improved performance with numba, maybe it could be even better with some more advanced set up but current results fully satisfy me so all I needed to do is add decorators, now it looks like this and works much faster, from 1,5h to 30sec:

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def minmax(v):
    if v > 255:
        v = 255
    if v < 0:
        v = 0
    return v

@jit(nopython=True)
def dithering_gray(inMat, samplingF):
    # grab the image dimensions
    h = inMat.shape[0]
    w = inMat.shape[1]

    # loop over the image
    for y in range(0, h - 1):
        for x in range(1, w - 1):
            # threshold the pixel
            old_p = inMat[y, x]
            new_p = np.round(samplingF * old_p / 255.0) * (255 / samplingF)
            inMat[y, x] = new_p

            quant_error_p = old_p - new_p

            inMat[y, x + 1] = minmax(inMat[y, x + 1] + quant_error_p * 7 / 16.0)
            inMat[y + 1, x - 1] = minmax(inMat[y + 1, x - 1] + quant_error_p * 3 / 16.0)
            inMat[y + 1, x] = minmax(inMat[y + 1, x] + quant_error_p * 5 / 16.0)
            inMat[y + 1, x + 1] = minmax(inMat[y + 1, x + 1] + quant_error_p * 1 / 16.0)

    # return the thresholded image
    return inMat
```